# How to capture/extract streaming link/url in batch mode

Tags: streaming, url, links, capture

In FireFox, if Video DownloadHelpder installed, one can get the streaming link in the current web. eg http://www.examplevideo.tv/room1 and Video Download Helper will tell me the streaming link of this web eg https://video.examplevideo.tv/live/12345678?id=abcdefg

However, Video DownloadHelper cannot perform in batch mode, its a tedious task if I need to find out the streaming link of 50 websites!!! Is there any program can perform this task in batch mode? i.e. Supply a list of web addresses eg

```
www.examplevideo.tv/room1
www.examplevideo.tv/room2
www.examplevideo.tv/room3
www.examplevideo.tv/room4
www.examplevideo.tv/room5
```

and it will return a list of streaming link to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`youtube-dl` (https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) has an option to produce the link: `--get-url`:

```
$ youtube-dl --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T8tyovvSDE
WARNING: unable to extract uploader nickname
https://r4---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/e93...
https://r4---sn-3pm76n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/e93...
```

`youtube-dl` supports much more than just YouTube. `youtube-dl` supports having more than one URL in the arguments. Just get out an editor and write `youtube-dl` followed by all the URLs you need, separated by a space.

Comment: It works for me, thx.